# Second query not working in Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The second query below does not work. It does not even execute the success neither error callback.
However, if I run each of them separately in different files, both work individually.

The second query does not give any feedback, no error message neither enters in success callback.
I have no idea how to debug it.

Would someone know how to solve it ?

```
downloadAlbums(callback) {
    const vueEnv = this;
    let db = firebase.firestore();
    let albumsRef = db.collection('albums');
    albumsRef.orderBy("createdAt", "desc").get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    vueEnv.items.push(doc);
                });
                callback(); // This callback refers to async seq
            });
},

countPhotos(callback) {

    let db = firebase.firestore();

    // [UPDATE: ADDING RANDOM WRITE OPERATION, ACCORDING JEFF'S COMMENT]
    db.collection("test").add({test:'test'})
    .then(function(docRef) { console.log('set') })
    .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error on setting: ", error);
    });
    // [END OF UPDATE]

    for (index in this.items) {

        let albumId = this.items[index].id;
        console.log("id: " + albumId);
        let photosRef = db.collection('albums').doc(albumId).collection('photos');
        photosRef.orderBy("createdAt", "desc").get()
        // it never calls the callback of then() or catch() function
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                if (querySnapshot.exists) {
                    console.log("querySnapshot.exists");
                } else {
                    console.log( "Do Not Exist In DB");
                };
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
     }
     callback();
},

// just for context
mounted: function () {
   this.$nextTick(function () {
       this.initializeFirebase();
       async.seq(this.downloadAlbums, this.countPhotos)(function(err, data) {
           console.log('seq concluded');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're entering the loop? Does this.items contain anything?

Comment: Yes. I've just added a console.log() inside the loop for debugging purpose.

Comment: We've seen that Firestore reads can sometimes get stuck - it's a known issue that should be fixed soon. Can you do a write, and then retry the query? That will often 'unstick' it and allow your read to complete normally.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I added a random write operation before the second read an it worked (please see updated code). It's a very tricky issue. Would you know where I can track it ? Regards.

Comment: Glad that worked! We're hoping to release a fix soon, but can't share any timelines. The release notes are the best place to watch for a fix: https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

Comment: I am having the same issue. The first read to my database runs, but any read after that nothing happens.

Comment: Just ran into this issue, I found that I had to wait exactly 10 seconds before I could perform a second query if its any help